# "No privilege" when creating table with Organization index

Tags: oracle11g, schema, create-table, privileges, tablespace

I am running Oracle 11.g and the id I am using has DBA role (full access supposedly).

When I tried to create a table under another schema, it works fine.  However, when I tried to create a table **with organization index**, I was prompted

```
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace
```

I double checked my id has unlimited tablespace.  My ID and the targeted schema are both in the same tablespace.

Supplemental info: I am able to run the same creat table statement w/ organization index under my own schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating objects may require two privileges: your user needs privileges to create the objects, and the schema owner needs privileges to use resources related to that object.  So while you have the ability to create a table in another schema, that schema also needs the privileges to write data to the related tablespaces:

```
alter user $username quota unlimited on $tablespace;
```

This approach is safer than granting the `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` role.  That role grants more than necessary, and if someone later tries to cleanup the privileges, revoking that role also undoes individual privileges, as described in [this article](https://blog.pythian.com/be-careful-when-revoking-unlimited-tablespace/).

Answer (score 1):

I granted the targeted schedma unlimited tablespace and it's resolved.

Comment: You might want to only give access to the necessary tablespace, through `alter user $username quota unlimited on $tablespace;`  Granting the unlimited tablespace role can cause problems later; if someone tries to cleanup the privileges, revoking that role also undoes individual privileges, as described in [this article](https://blog.pythian.com/be-careful-when-revoking-unlimited-tablespace/).

Comment: @thanks Jon...your approach is better...can you post this as an answer and I'll accept it.  thx!